# Name a soft link something that isnt the folder's name

Tags: unix, symlink, ln

This line:

```
sudo ln -s ~/Desktop/backup/massive_folder /var/www/
```

makes: `/var/www/massive_folder` with the functionality of massive_folder being linked to in the place that I want it linked to. This is good.

I just want `massive_folder` to be name `html`

I want: `/var/www/html` with the contents of `massive_folder`

Answer (score 0):

simply `cp -r massive_folder html`